# Why does Helly keep repeating the apology in the Break Room? Why can't she refuse reading that text?

Tags: severance

At the beginning of the fourth episode of *Severance* Season 1, why does Helly keep repeating the apology (or "compunction statement", according to Milchick) in the Break Room?

> Forgive me for the harm I have caused this world. None may atone for my actions but me and only in me shall their stain live on. I am thankful to have been caught, my fall cut short by those with wizened hands. All I can be is sorry, and that is all I am.

Why can't she refuse reading that text? She seems alive and awake enough to want to leave.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you be more specific about what "stupid stuff" you're referring to?

Comment: i suppose they are talking about the "break room". i wondered the same thing, she doesn't even try to refuse.

Answer (score 7):

**Milchik will not let her leave.**

In fact, when it gets late, and Milchik is still not satisfied with Helly's reading, he simply says they'll pick it up again in the morning.  One elevator trip later, and for Helly, it is morning, and Milchik is waiting for her to take her straight back to the Break Room.

There is no situation where she gets out of this.  Milchik will not let her just go back to work.  Mark is below Milchik in the pecking order.  Leaving the severed floor will not give her freedom - it just gives control back to the outside Helly R, who later that same episode makes clear she expects the inside Helly R to do what shes told.

Answer (score 5):

It is revealed that **severed employees who went to the Break Room receive injuries**, heavily implied to be **resulting from physical punishment/torture or self-harm due to resisting punishment**.

It can be inferred that Helly was also threatened with the same punishment.

In S01E06 "Hide and Seek", Mark (outie) has this conversation with Alexa, his date, in the scene that immediately followed the scene where Mark S. (innie) entered the Break Room:

> **Alexa:** What happened to your hand?
> **Mark:** Mmm. Apparently, I jammed my hand at work replenishing a watercooler. Or at least that's what they tell me.
> **Alexa:** Those jugs are very heavy.
> **Mark:** Mmm. Indeed they are.

Screencap of Mark's injured hand after a Break Room session:

[image: screencap of Mark's injured hand]

Either Mark was physically punished to the point of injury, or he resisted whatever was being done to him in the break room, causing him to injure his own hands. Either way, that was definitely not from a water cooler accident.

---

The hand injuries among Lumon's severed employees were also referenced in S01E09 "The We We Are", the Season 1 finale episode. It was revealed that Irving's outie has been collating information about Lumon's severed floor and severed employees. He has a newspaper clipping about a hand injury that a severed employee named Dalton Emery, got:

[image: screencap of news clip mentioned above]

> Kier, PE - Today marks the first of many long days in court for what is sure to be one of the region's more contentious civil trials in recent memory. **The plaintiff, Dalton Emory, is suing his former employer, Lumon, in an attempt to get his former employer to divulge the accurate details pertaining to an injury that occurred while he was Severed and on company property.** Emory claims that when he passed the severance threshold on his way home from a day at work, his left hand begun to throb violently. By the time he arrived at his car, the throbbing morphed into sharp shooting pain. "I saw an envelope with my name carefully placed under his windshield. When I opened the envelope I was given the Lumon version of the injury that occurred that day, ‘Dear Mr Emory, Whilst replacing—“
>
> “-work, the doctor insisted that still having pain is common with printer related injuries. The doctor gave him a salve, and told him to apply it on the finger twice daily, and that he should take it easy and relax. The salve did nothing, and a few days later Emory no longer had feeling in his left index finger, rendering the digit decorative. He consulted with a doctor who was not on Lumon’s payroll. **The specialist determined that his injury was most likely caused by a blunt force, not by an accidental crushing injury as the company had suggested.**
>
> “-unethical.’ The doctor had recommended that Emory try using leeches to help regain the blood flow to his fingertip. Emory has said he is willing to do just about anything to regain the sensations he has lost. He now finds himself struggling with elevator buttons, selecting his preferred gas variety, and entering his pin number. His life forever changed by this injury.
>
> Emory's doctor believes that his outcome may not have been as severe if he were given the full story and appropriate medical attention. **He is now suing Lumon in an effort to ascertain the un-falsified information regarding his injury**, and a cash settlement to offset past and future medical bills. The plantiffs’ legal counsel is confident that they will be able to sway a jury. His lawyer, Mick Therdone, agreed to comment on the trial: “Now that permanent damage has occured, Lumon needs to be held accountable.”

<sup>- The transcribed newspaper clipping is from the Reddit /r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus post: [“Lumon needs to be held accountable” (Transcribed newspaper article from S1E9)](https://www.reddit.com/r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus/comments/u02k74/lumon_needs_to_be_held_accountable_transcribed/) (emphasis mine).</sup>

---

*[Severance — The Lexington Letter](https://books.apple.com/us/book/severance/id1613220757)* (ebook), which tells the story of Lumon employee Margaret “Peg” Kincaid, suggests that severed employees in the Break Room may be tortured by waterboarding. Peg was able to communicate with her innie, Peggy K., through "Puglish", an alphabet that Peg and her sister made up as kids, which Peggy K. somehow also knew how to read and write.

Peg narrates:

> One Tuesday, I emerged to find my hair wet. A note on my windshield from Lumon informed me that my innie had had a “visually comedic but painless mishap with the water cooler”. I was given a gift card to Murray’s All-Day Breakfast Buffet as an apology for the inconvenience.

Peggy K.'s (innie) reply to Peg's last note:

> Dooley found your last note. Been in Break Room. Don't know how long. [...]

The similar water cooler "mishap" suggests that severed employees in the Break Room are being tortured.

Comment: Helly would't have known any of this, though.

Comment: @ths Helly didn't need to know any of that. She just needs to be threatened with punishment.